# Why I am getting this output?

Tags: c, output

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000     // Maximum array size 

int main() {
    int arr[MAX_SIZE], size, i;
    int max1, max2;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    max1 = max2 = -99999;
    /* Input array elements */ 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    /*
     * Check for first largest and second
     */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max1) {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = arr[i];
        } else
        if (arr[i] > max2 && arr[i] < max1) {
            max2 = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", max2);
    return 0;
}
```

when I used test case `20 10 40 4 100` output is correct `40`,
but when I use `1 2 3 4 5` then output is `max2 = -99999`.

Can anyone please explain to me why I am not getting this? I traced but did not get why?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this.

Comment: You didn't say whether you were entering "5" (size of the array) before entering those other inputs. I suppose you did since the program would behave differently (prompt the wrong number of times for inputs), but it's unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is somewhat consistent with the input, assuming the input comes from a text file:

- the first number read is the number of entries to handle.
- for the first case, `size` is read as `20` and the program tries to read 20 numbers into `arr[0]` through `arr[19]`. As you do not test the return value of `scanf()`, you do not detect the invalid or missing input past the last one in the file `100`. `scanf()` fails and leaves `arr[i]` unchanged from index `4` on. `arr` is unintiialized, so the contents is undefined and so is the behavior of the program. It so happens that there are no numbers in `arr[4]` through `arr[19]` that are larger than 40. So the second largest number is printed as `40`.
- for the second case, `size` is read as `1` and only a single number is read into `arr[0]`, the remaining input being ignored. The loop sets `max1 = 2` and `max2 = max1`, whose initial value is `-99999`. Hence the output.

You should provide `5 20 10 40 4 100` and `5 1 2 3 4 5` as input to get the expected behavior consistently.

You should also be more defensive with user input and report unexpected cases:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000     // Maximum array size 

int main() {
    int arr[MAX_SIZE], size, i;
    int max1, max2, has_max;
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1) {
        printf("missing count of numbers\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (size < 0 || size > MAX_SIZE) {
        printf("invalid count of numbers: %i\n", size);
        return 1;
    }
    /* Input array elements */ 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input: got %i numbers instead of %i\n", i, size);
            size = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    /*
     * Check for first largest and second
     */
    max1 = max2 = INT_MIN;
    has_max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max1) {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = arr[i];
            has_max++;
        } else
        if (arr[i] > max2 && arr[i] < max1) {
            max2 = arr[i];
            has_max++;
        }
    }
    if (has_max < 2) {
        printf("no second highest value\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", max2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the method to track if there are at least 2 different values in the array. Try and see if this improvement is sufficient for all cases...

Comment: good I get it works fine when I remove scanf("%d", &size); But it gives wrong output for 0 0 0 0 0 output : max2 = -99999 but actual should be 0 explain me this also.

Comment: @NitinSaini: if the problem states that the input starts with the count of number to handle, the above code works and the explanation for the observed behavior holds. If the problem states that you should find the second largest number in a set of 5 numbers, remove the initial `scanf()` and set `size = 5` (and probably define `arr` to just `int arr[MAX_SIZE]`).

Comment: @NitinSaini: there is no second largest entry in `0 0 0 0 0` as all values are equal to `max1`. The problem should state how to handle this special case.

Comment: @NitinSaini: if the expected output for `0 0 0 0 0` is `0`, add `if (has_max == 1) max2 = max1;`

Answer (score 3):

In your program, the first input is the size of the array. So, your inputs should actually be `5 20 10 40 4 100` and `5 1 2 3 4 5` (note the extra 5 in front) so they have the correct size. Your first input is correct because it read in `20` as the size and tried to read in 20 numbers, and there weren't enough numbers so it just read in 0 for the rest, and 40 was still the second-largest. For your second input, it read in 1 as the size, so there was no second-largest number, so it printed out -99999.

Comment: Good explanation, but you might explain why the incorrect input produces `40` for the first case and `-99999` for the second.

Comment: what you are trying to say I didn't get it? what should I do tell me properly

Comment: @NitinSaini The answerer thinks you incorrectly inputted your numbers because we are unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Aplet good I get it works fine when I remove  `scanf("%d", &size);` But it give wrong output for 0 0 0 0 0  output : `max2 = -99999` but actual should be 0 explain me this also.

Comment: Because you now don't even have a size.

Comment: @NitinSaini You probably shouldn't remove size unless you hardcode it as something. Assuming you hardcoded `5` as `size`, this now doesn't work because your program doesn't account for the possibility of all identical arguments. Changing `arr[i] > max1` to `arr[i] >= max1` may be a fix.

Comment: "*and there weren't enough numbers so it just read in 0 for the rest, and 40 was still the second-largest*" - That is not possible. The control flow doesn't continue if `scanf()`  found no input in `stdin` and does not assign `0` to the rest elements. It will wait for more input instead.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: `scanf()` will wait for more input except in 2 cases: 1) if the next character in the input cannot start a number, it returns `0` and does not consume this pending character, hence all subsequent calls to `scanf()` will return 0 immediately without modifying `arr[i]`, which will remain unintialized and the program's behavior is undefined. 2) if `scanf()` reaches the end of the file, which is likely what happens for the OP. `scanf()` returns `EOF` in this case and also leaves `arr[i]` unchanged with the same consequences. Always check `scanf()` return value.